# Deleting duplicate records in the attribute table and keep the minimum value in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, duplication

I have two fields: **ID_PARCEL** and **NL**. The **ID_PARCEL** is the field that contains duplicate records. I would like to remove the duplicate record by keeping the minimum **NL** field value. For example: the value 22 in the **ID_PARCEL** field is duplicated, so the row of the attributes table that should be removed is the one with the highest value in the **NL** field, which in this case is the value 627.

I searched on the site, but what I found was deleting duplicate records without the condition to keep the minimum value of another field. Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: it's possible to do this without code using SQL (even if you're not using a database). Or do you want to use pyqgis specifically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question, you may use the following code:

```
layer= iface.activeLayer() # load the layer as you want
vals = {} # create an empty dictionary

# Let's populate the dictionary
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    if feat['ID_PARCEL'] not in vals:
        vals[feat['ID_PARCEL']] = [feat['NL']]
    else:
        vals[feat['ID_PARCEL']].append(feat['NL'])

# Let's find the minimum value from the "NL" field for each "ID_PARCEL" field
for key, value in vals.iteritems():
    vals[key] = min(value)

# Let's delete the unwanted features
with edit(layer):
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        k = feature['ID_PARCEL']
        if feature['NL'] != vals[k]:
            layer.deleteFeature(feature.id())
```

Since the edits will apply immediately, please **create a backup copy** of the original data before running the above code.

Comment: If i change the field names to the field names i have, all is deleted, why?